# javascript regex after specific text

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to pull out only the text part(not special character !@#$%^&*()...)
In this case, I want to pull `javascriptbye` which can change, but `for` is stable.

```js
var phrase = "helloworldpython2000forjavascript)bye";
var myPattern = /for(.*)/
```

`myPattern` pulls out all texts, javascript)bye. I tried `/for(.[a-zA-Z]+$/` but no luck.
How can I change it, so that I can have text after specific word?

Thanks!
**EDIT**
`phrase` could include space as well.

```js
var phrase = "hello world python 2000 for javascript ) bye";
var myPattern = /for(.*)/
```

Comment: What method are you using? `search`, `match`, `exec`?

Comment: @empiric I am using `match`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **Positive Lookbehind**

```
/(?<=for.*)[\w]+/g
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GNXWcE/1)**

```js
var phrase = "helloworldpython2000forjavascript)bye";
var myPattern = /(?<=for.*)[\w]+/g

console.log(phrase.match(myPattern))
```

https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind

Comment: It works well even with space. Does yours take care space?

Comment: @jayko03 `\w` is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 1):

you can replace using regex

```js
var phrase = "helloworldpython2000forjavascript)bye";
console.log(phrase.replace(/.*for?/, "").replace(/[!@#$&()\\-`.+,\/\"]/, ""))
```